# Unable to validate Error message using selenium

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium-webdriver, assert

I am trying to validate the message which comes on the web page after performing an action (updating/creation of any records in  the system.)
The problem is the message disappear after 3-4 seconds, and hence I am unable to capture any changes in DOM(Javascript)

Attached is the screenshot -
[image]
I tried `BrowserDriver.getBrowserDriver().getPageSource().contains("warning message here")` with assertTrue() statement but its not working.

please let me know the approach

Comment: How the `DOM` looks like when then message pops up? I had to do similar stuff with toaster

Comment: Similar to this... I am sure since the message disappear in 2-3 seconds, I cant capture the DOM. `<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $("div.fadable").delay(2000)
        .fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("div.fadable").remove();
        }); 
//<![CDATA[`
</script>

Comment: This looks like the script. But, the message could be a div or some other tag. can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes the message is in `<div class="message success fadable">..</div>` However, I can not see the details as the message disappears soon and so is this div class

Comment: Are you using Selenium `Java` bindings?And, can is that a pulic site?

Comment: Yeah I am using Selenium java and its a public site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74525/discussion-between-saifur-and-yougandhara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the following code a try. Note: the selector is written in a way to identify the element based on the failure *div* text. Please make sure the text inside the selector is as it is appeared in the message(specially whitespace). I always suggest you to find the element depending on the class/id if that is unique if possible

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Failed To Save')]");

WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver,5)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would like to set implicitlyWait property as little as possible:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then it's better to use ExpectedConditions to catch that element:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("your-element")));
```

So you don't need to use assertTrue() or anything like this, WebDriverWait fails if it can't find an element.

Don't forget to change implicitlyWait value after, back to the default one.

Comment: How can I define the xpath when the webpage message disappear only in 2 seconds? Also can't we use getPageSource().contains() mehod for this?

Comment: @sap1ens It's **NOT** recommended by [SeleniumHQ](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#webdriver-advanced-usage) to mix up implicit and explicit waits. It can cause some unexpected performance issue. And, it's considered as bad practice